# what is the state of the art method for hedging barrier options?

Tags: options, option-pricing, hedging, exotics

I want to create my own Barrier options for some security, I want to trade. I did some literature review, and found a static replication method, and many dynamic replication methods. I want to know what is the state of the art method, like what do banks use to hedge there risk in practice in 2019.